# How do I retrieve dates of predictions using Weka timeseriesForecasting?

Tags: java, time-series, weka, forecasting

I am using the Weka Forecaster to predict some values, however, I do not understand how to retrieve the dates for each prediction as you would get in the Weka GUI.

I set the time stamp like this:

```
 forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setTimeStampField("date");
```

I then build and prime my forecaster with the data from the arff file, the predictor is set to predict 2 values, which it does. And I then fetch them like this:

```
List<List<NumericPrediction>> forecast = forecaster.forecast(5, System.out);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            List<NumericPrediction> predsAtStep = forecast.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print("Item " + j + ": " + predsAtStep.get(j).predicted() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

I thought that you might be able to just enter the date as one of the fields to forecast and that would work, using  forecaster.setFieldsToForecast, it did not.

Any idea on how I could get the date for each prediction?

Answer (score 0):

That's because "date" is your x-axis variable, and you don't forecast that axis. The prediction is on the field at a specified date.

The date value can be obtained (calculated) from `forecast.getTSLagMaker().getCurrentTimeStampValue()` and `forecast.getTSLagMaker().getDeltaTime()` depending on how you setup your forecaster, otherwise look at the API: [Weka javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/timeseriesForecasting/)

Comment: I am forecasting 5 units and want to know the date for each of these predictions. I'm not sure what date I am getting from what you are suggesting (I get 8.64E7) but I can't use getTSLagMaker on each prediction only on the forecaster and that will only give me the one date in an odd format. I tried predicting the date as well but that does not work either. 

I could manually keep track of dates if I knew the last day before the predictions  started and increment that (but then I have to skip weekends somehow)